# Considering governor limits when coding a LWC with callouts

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, governorlimits

Let's say that we are supposed to design a LWC that would:

- Show a list of items which would be returned from a Web Service (LWC is rendered, callout is automatically made, JSON array of objects is returned).
- For each item in the list, there would be a button which would perform another callout to a Web Service and return details of a certain item, again in JSON.

How would an experienced developer consider [governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) in this example?

> - Total number of callouts (HTTP requests or web services calls) in a    transaction - Synchronous 100, Asynchronous 100
> - Maximum cumulative timeout for all callouts (HTTP requests or Web    services calls) in a transaction - Synchronous 120 sec, Asynchronous 120 sec

Comment: Are the callouts being made in JavaScript or Apex? Can you articulate where the transaction boundaries (if any) are located, and does that help you understand where these limits will and will not impact you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) Show a list of items which would be returned from a Web Service (LWC is rendered, callout is automatically made, JSON array of objects is returned).

This sounds like 1 callout per component instantiation.

> b) For each item in the list, there would be a button which would perform another callout to a Web Service and return details of a certain item, again in JSON.

This sounds like 1 callout per button click.

Keep in mind that *each* Apex method you call from Aura/LWC gets its *own* governor limits, so it sounds like you'd not go over 1 callout of the 100 callout limit.

Comment: Drafting my comment with similar details. But, this answer provides even more details.